# Google Sheets - query for one tab works great but I get Value error when adding a 2nd tab to the query

Tags: database, google-sheets

In a Google Sheet I am wanting to compile data from a specific date across multiple tabs chosen by using Query and Select. My formula works perfectly for the query of 1 tab, but when I add a second tab (there are about 17 in total I want to add), I get the following VALUE error:

> "Function QUERY parameter 3 expects number values. But 'select * where B=date '2021-10-12' order by C ASC' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number."

Here is a link to an editable copy of the document. The formula is in the first tab (Schedule), cell A3:

[Editable copy of the sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xcSXliViKv0VOOfFcvQhWHRjc_1JcRMRQ8p1JhI4Jjc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: looks like its solved

Comment: To whoever solved the formula for me - THANK YOU!!